# Excel Sheet not getting opened in SSIS Script Task without manually saving once

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I am trying to open an excel file in SSIS Script task and I am using below connection string for the same.

`ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileFullPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1 \"";`

This does not open up the excel and gives error while connecting to Excel. However, the same code works when I open excel file and save it manually. There are a lot of files so I do not want to save them manually every time.

I also tried to access this file through SQL Openrowset. It also has same issues.

Please help me if someone faced such problem earlier.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How were the excel files generated? Some excel libraries generate seemingly fine excel files, but they can't be opened in some tools

Comment: Excel Files are generated through Python using "xlsxwriter.Workbook()". Also, 1MB file generated by Python becomes 200KB after saving it manually.

Comment: Basically Python is not generating a file that is 'agreeable'. Is it an option to generate a text delimited file instead (i.e. tab delimited) This is a far more suitable format for data transfer

Comment: Actually, these excel files are kind of reports having a lot of formatting, tabs and are also used directly for analysis.

Comment: That makes them even less suitable for import by SSIS. If you are stuck with them then you can do a mass convert. Here's some example code https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/4/23/loop-through-all-excel-files-in-a-given-folder